# Copy and Paste Webpage Elements

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Im used to scraping data in c# but I want to know if you can copy and paste from a browser.
Lets say you load a site, you can highlight any elements you want and copy them, then paste in say - word. The layout and view look pretty much the same.

Is it possible to do this in code and I dont mean using HTMLAgilityPack or similar to grab elements by the HTML. I want to copy and paste from the UI programatically.
Can this be done?

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to copy, say, a hyperlink and copy it to a Word document?

Comment: Pretty much but on a slightly larger scale.
Like a selection of tables and their general layout. Copy and paste from the browser works fine, just need to know if it can be done in code.

Comment: It can, yes.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing more than google searchs and trying to look for any functions in the webbrowser that would allow an area selection and copy of the UI but nothing..

Comment: Have you looked into [WatiN](http://watin.org/) at all?